# How do I mark a user as admin in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am building a ruby on rails application using mysql for storing application related data. My application has a user console and admin console. Access to admin console is restricted to administrators. How do I mark a user as admin in mysql database.

Comment: Dunno. How does your application determine that someone is an admin?

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was a mysql configuration. Didn't know it was application dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Easy to mark a user as admin inside of mysql -
 add another mysql user as documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html
 and grant them appropriate permissions as documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

as to connecting to the database as separate users, that's another ball of wax with overriding methods...

or are you talking about making an admin flag in the users table...that's a column with the boolean type